# Laravel — Loop all data from multiple tables

Tags: laravel-5, relationship

Good day. I have researched about it, but nothings matched with my problem. Here's the scenario. I have `courses` table, and `3` more tables, `assignments`, `quizzes`, and `reports`. Now, what I want is, to get all of the **records** from the table `assignments`, `quizzes`, and `reports` and **loop** through all the records below a specific `course`. 
**Example Output: The order should be according to the first created item.**
`Course1`
  `Assignment1`
  `Quiz1` 
  `Quiz2` 
  `Assignment2` 
  `Report1`

How can I do that with **three** different tables? I know how to use the basic `many to many` relationship, but for this. I really got stacked. Need help guys. 
`Note: I'm using Laravel5.1`

**Update1** `— Course.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Course extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [];

    public function assignments(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('Assignment');
    }

    public function quizzes(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('Quiz');
    }

    public function reports(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('Report');
    }

}
```

**UPDATE2 as per request**

```
<div class="table">
                <table class="tabled">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>x</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    @foreach($course_items as $course_item)
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <a href="#">{{ $table_name }} {{ $course_item->name }}</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
```

Comment: Update your question to include your model and relationship definitions, and required output.

Comment: I have already an example output and I have now included the `model`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the limited information available from your question, you will need to merge your relations into a single collection.

Using unions would be a better solution, if feasible, to improve efficiency, but hey-ho.

```
// Prepare not deleted scope
// I would suggest using Laravel's SoftDeletes, as it'll be better than writing your own implementation. But if not, you would be better to create this as a reusable scope on your model
$notDeletedScope = function ($query) {
    return $query->where('deleted', 0);
};

// Find course with non-deleted relations
$course = Course::with([
        'assignments' => $notDeletedScope,
        'reports'     => $notDeletedScope,
        'quizzes'     => $notDeletedScope,
    ])
    ->findOrFail($id);

// Combine relations into single collection
$merged = collect($course->assignments);
$merged = $merged->merge(collect($course->quizzes));
$merged = $merged->merge(collect($course->reports));

// Sort merged relations by created_at
$merged = $merged->sortBy('created_at');

@foreach ($merged as $relation)
    @if ($relation->type === 'assignment')
        // ...
    @elseif ($relation->type === 'quiz')
        // ...
    @elseif ($relation->type === 'report')
        // ...
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Add to each model:

```
public function getTypeAttribute()
{
    return snake_case(substr(strrchr(get_class($this), '\\'), 1));
}
```

Comment: I already got this idea. But what if the first item that was created is a `quiz`? or `report`?

Comment: Are you saying you want them in date order? I didn't see that mentioned in your question. I ask again, if you can be *specific* about your required output, then it will be easier to suggest solutions.

Comment: Oh, indeed men. sorry

Comment: It is working now. But, how can I determine if the item is from the `assignments` table, or `quizzes` table?

Comment: Use the class name, table name, or add an attribute getter to return a type.

Comment: I'll try it later sir, after I created `quizzes`. I am now working on it.

Comment: How can I do that? I am using `{{ $course_item->name }}` this code now to print the items.

Comment: @Mr.J update your question to show where your code is at and what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Mr.J - okay, but what are you trying to achieve? Why does the new code you posted not work? Does each relation not have a `name` attribute?

Comment: Hm, I just want to get the `table` of each looped item. I will update my question a little bit.

Comment: Is `$table_name` the name of the database table?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145500/discussion-between-mr-j-and-fubar).

Comment: @Mr.J - updated my answer with a suggestion to solve your problem.

Comment: I got it now. Last thing. How can I add `where('deleted', 0)` ? It is working if I add it in my `view` inside the `foreach` loop, but it is not efficient because every item, it triggers a query, so it will run slower.

Comment: You're using your own soft deletion implementation instead of using `SoftDeletes`?

Comment: Yes sir. Thats what Im using

Comment: You're using `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes`? If yes and the trait is applied to your models you shouldn't need to do anything to exclude deleted models.

Comment: No sir. Just added `deleted` column in my database

Comment: Updated answer with additional comments.

Comment: I dont want to use `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes` because it excluded all deleted item. There's something I want to do with it.

Comment: You can override that behaviour when required using the `withTrashed` query scope.

Comment: I also want to show the deleted Items, but with the red background

Comment: I don't understand. Is your problem fixed or not?

Comment: Ow, indeed. sorry for that. I'm just going to create another topic. anyways, Thank you so much. You're such a great laravel warrior!